# Polymer 1.1 Paper-Header-Panel Breakage in Template

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

With polymer 1.1, I am having 2 issues with `paper-header-panel`

1. I can't not get the content below the panel to show
2. I can't get the `height: 2000px;` to be applied to the `div` so I
   can have a scrolling bar to have the waterfall effect.

I was using https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-header-panel/blob/master/demo/index.html as example to go by.

After doing some trouble shooting `div id="mainContainer"` is 0 height. If remove the flex from the class, then the height it applied. But then this breaks the scrolling waterfall effect.

```
<dom-module id="custom-paper-header-panel">

  <template>
  <style>
    #foobar {
      height: 2000px;
    }
  </style>

    <paper-header-panel mode="waterfall-tall">
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div class='title'></div>
        <paper-tabs>
          <paper-tab>
            <div>contact</div>
          </paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
        <div class='title bottom'>
          <h1 id="name-title">foo</h1>
        </div>
      </paper-toolbar>
      <div id="foobar">
          <h2>This isn't being shown</h2>
      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "custom-paper-header-panel"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element looks fine. The issue is probably caused by your `custom-paper-header-panel` element defined on your page not having a `Height` applied to it.

Try making it `fit`.

```
<custom-paper-header-panel class="fit"></custom-paper-header-panel>
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1FHMDkUSthmKiwVQmcIe?p=preview) for a working sample.

Comment: Still no success. I also tried css `html { height: 100% }` to no success.

Comment: I guess it's got something to do with your page. Can you share some code?

Comment: Just wanted to note to others that might have this issue: This didn't work for me in `template`, but did as a non custom element.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I think the documentation isn't exactly clear on this because it gives **most** examples without the below attributes... but if you want a full blown header(which is probably 99% of the time) you are supposed to use:

```
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <paper-header-panel  class="flex">
```

Comment: like I explained in my answer, your `paper-header-panel` doesn't render properly because it needs to be properly sized, which basically means that you need to use either `fit` or `flex` layout or a fixed `height`. Your answer is only another way to solve the same problem.

Comment: well....need more than that... also need `<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">`. I think needing height may be a little misleading because I had `height: 100%` .

Comment: If you use `flex` then yes, you need that. But if you use my answer with `fit` then you don't. See the attached plunker example.

Comment: Nice! That works! Didn't work in `template` but I don't care about making it a custom element anymore.

Comment: Didn't work in template probably because its parent doesn't have position set to relative. :)

Comment: wouldn't `html { height: 100% }` set it?

Comment: It might not. It's like saying `100%` of *its parent*, but this *parent* might not fill the entire page. So when you do that, make sure its parent is sized properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in Polymer. If you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of the page then Paper-header-panel does not work.

Try to **remove the doctype declaration**. It solves my problem.